# Find the decreasing range of the function: $f(x)=xe^{\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, inequality, exponential-function

> Find the decreasing range of the function:
>
> $$f(x)=xe^{\sin x}.$$

I found derivative $$f'(x)=(xe^{\sin x})'=e^{\sin x} (x \cos x + 1)$$

But I couldn't solve this inequality:

$$f'(x)≤0 \Longrightarrow e^{\sin x} (x \cos x + 1)≤0$$

$$x \cos x + 1≤0$$

Comment: you must solve $$x\cos(x)+1\le 0$$

Comment: Note that the exponential term is always positive

Comment: Yes, You are right..I understood now. $e^x>0$